# How To Increase Performance of Merge Statement in DB2

Tags: performance, merge, db2

I have two table one is very BIG and another is relatively very Smaller.
I am using merge statement for updating the BIG_TABLE like below.

merge into BIG_TABLE t1
    USING( 
                Select col1, col2 ,col3
                from SMALL_TABLE
                where  condition1 and condition2 
          ) t2
    on ( 
            t1.col1 = t2.col1
            and t1.col2=t2.col2
        )
    when matched then
        UPDATE SET t1.col3=t2.col3

But its taking too much time . 
Big table has some 1M data while small is having 10k. 
Is using merge statement here is optimum????

Comment: Are the tables organized by row or column?  If row based, what indexes exist on both tables?  Recent runstats completed?

Comment: Col1 and col2 are part of primary key in both tables. col3 which is updating is not part of key nor its using in any index . Indexes is both the tables are their priamary key which is consist of col1, col2 and some more columns .
I am not certain about how tables organized could you please elaborate.

Comment: Have you checked the access plan ?  Which Db2-platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows) ?  Which db2 version?

Comment: Have you run visual explain against the SQL? Does that recommend any indexes? Does your server have enough resources to run the query?

Comment: Its on zlinux, db2 version 10.5, how to access plan?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, it has enough resources . I didn't run. Kindly share the tool link.

Comment: Study the Db2 knowledge center and learn about db2exfmt. Link to doc is https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002353.html .  You can also use IBM DataStudio to view the access plan.  Study and training required. Verify that your runstats are up to date for both tables and all indexes. A 1-million rows is a tiny amount for Z hardware.

Comment: Thanks allot  @mao , I will go through this and get back to you.